# Upload File Error

Tags: upload, callback

I've used the followed example to upload files in my app:
http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/ 

At the Helper upload method, I've found the '$A.run' and it's not working anymore, so I took it off. And now, when I select the file to upload at the first time nothing happens, but if I do it again both files are uploaded. Summing up: Code inside 'setCallback' are only executed if upload twice.

```
    upload: function(component, file, fileContents) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveTheFile"); 

    action.setParams({
        parentId: component.get("v.parentId"),
        fileName: file.name,
        base64Data: encodeURIComponent(fileContents), 
        contentType: file.type
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        attachId = a.getReturnValue();
        console.log(attachId);
    });

    $A.run(function() {
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    });
}
```

Is there any idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you used is out of date now, `$A` has been deprecated, you now need to use `$A.getCallback()` instead. I've not dug deeply into this, but pretty sure this'll sort you out:

```
$A.getCallback(function() {
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
})();
```

Comment: Thank you @MattLacey ... Your solution fixed my problem!